# QTextCursor insertText not working

Tags: qt4

I'm trying to make a table in QT using QTextTable.  The first row working fine when I set background and text but the second row is only applying the formating but the insertText function doesn't seem to work for me.  I've also tried insertHTML but nothing seems to work for me on row2.

```
QTextTableFormat channelBankFormat;
channelBankFormat.setAlignment(Qt::AlignHCenter);
//channelBankFormat.setHeight(8);
channelBankFormat.setColumnWidthConstraints(constraints);
channelBankFormat.setBorder(0);

ChannelBank->clear();
QTextCursor cursor = ChannelBank->textCursor();
cursor.beginEditBlock();

QTextTable *table = cursor.insertTable(2, 5, channelBankFormat);
QTextCharFormat headerFormat = cursor.charFormat();
headerFormat.setFontWeight(QFont::Bold);
headerFormat.setFontPointSize(8);

QTextCharFormat dataFormat = cursor.charFormat();
dataFormat.setFontPointSize(12);

QTextBlockFormat centerAlignment;
centerAlignment.setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);

for (int cellNumber = 1; cellNumber <= 5; ++cellNumber) {
    QTextTableCell  cell                = table->cellAt(0, cellNumber-1);
    QTextCharFormat headerCellFormat    = cell.format();
    QTextCursor     cellCursor          = cell.firstCursorPosition();

    headerCellFormat.setBackground(QColor(0 + (cellNumber * 50), 222, 222, 127));
    cell.setFormat(headerCellFormat);
    cellCursor.clearSelection();
    cellCursor.insertText("---",headerFormat);
}
for (int cellNumber = 1; cellNumber <= 5; ++cellNumber) {
    QTextTableCell  cell                = table->cellAt(1, cellNumber-1);
    QTextCharFormat headerCellFormat    = cell.format();
    QTextCursor     cellCursor          = cell.lastCursorPosition();

    headerCellFormat.setBackground(QColor(0 + (cellNumber * 50), 222, 222, 127));
    cell.setFormat(headerCellFormat);
    cellCursor.clearSelection();
    cellCursor.insertText("---",headerFormat);
}
cursor.endEditBlock();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the culprit : 
    channelBankFormat.setHeight(8);